# How would I give Full Calendar a JSON Feed for events in Java/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, fullcalendar

I have written java methods in a servlet to return a collection and parse through documents to return a JSONArray of JSON Objects.. here is my code 
Java Servlet POST METHOD!

```
EmployeeSchedule_CRUD obj = new EmployeeSchedule_CRUD();
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = obj.getCollection();


        JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(); // outer Array
        FindIterable<Document> iterateDocuments = collection.find();
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = iterateDocuments.iterator();

        long documentCount = collection.countDocuments();
        System.out.println( "Document count " + documentCount);

//      System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
        for(Document doc: iterateDocuments)
        {
            JSONObject jsonOBJ = new JSONObject(); // row Array 
            try {
                jsonOBJ.put("title", doc.get("Title"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonOBJ.put("start", doc.get("Start"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonOBJ.put("end", doc.get("End"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonOBJ.put("color", doc.get("Color"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            jsonArray1.put(jsonOBJ);



        }

        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonArray1;



    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(jsonArray2.toString());
```

Here is the calendar.js file , I have seen some examples within the fullcalendar docs and stack overflow.

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        if ($('#calendar').length) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                eventSources:[

                            {
                            url: '/RetrieveEmployeeSchedule',
                            method: 'POST',
                            failure: function()
                                        {
                                            alert('there was an error fetching events!');
                                        }

                            }
                        ]
            })
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And this is the ouput, but FullCalendar is not "accepting" it..if I put this exact format in the calendar.js file the calendar renders the events, so something may be wrong with my ajax call.. please help

```
[{"color":"#eb4034","start":"2020-06-20 13:00:00","end":"2020-06-26 20:00:00","title":"Troy Day Shift Working"},{"color":"#0fc1f7","start":"2020-06-20 22:00:00","end":"2020-06-28 09:00:00","title":"Vanessa Midnight Shift Working"},{"color":"#eb4034","start":"2020-07-01 10:00:00","end":"2020-07-09 17:00:00","title":"Ed Day Shift Working"},{},{"color":"#eb4034","start":"2020-07-01 10:00:00","end":"2020-07-09 17:00:00","title":"Ed Day Shift Working"}]
```

Comment: Have you checked what JSON is being output by the Java code, and whether the Ajax call is working? Use the network tool in your browser's Developer Tools to check

Comment: The above output is what my java servlet returns as a response, although in my ajax call in my calendar instance is getting an error "404 (Not Found)"  with errors relating to this..                                                                                                   
 send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
_fetchEventSource @ fullcalendar.js:11076

Comment: If you can access the servlet endpoint successfully via a separate request (which is what I understand you to mean by _"The above output is what my java servlet returns as a response"_), but the AJAX request returns a 404, then this likely means you specified the wrong URL (or possibly just the wrong HTTP method) in your AJAX settings. Use your browser's Network tool to check what full URL the request resolves to, and whether that's what you intended/expected. It's possibly just an issue with a relative URL path. Hard to know since we can't see your setup.